# OSX Terminal - export to csv list of files inside folder

Tags: macos, csv, terminal

-- CONTEXT and what's working so far --

I use this command in OSx Terminal to get a csv file with all filenames structured according to their paths, inside a folder:

```
find 'folder' -type f -print | sed 's_/_,_g' > ~/filelist.csv
```

Other info:

- Folder name - doesn't contain "duc" for sure
- Subfolders

a) Subfolders may or may not contain "duc" string in their name (as for now they don't but I can't be sure if it will happen or not in the future)

b) All subfolders may or may not contain files that contain the string in their names

-- WHAT I WOULD LIKE --

- That the filelist.csv would list/have filenames that contain a string in their name: "duc" and its variations - duc, DUC, DuC... (e.g. "12345 duc.pdf", "12345 DUC2.pdf")
- The list should also show filepaths
- It should be taken into consideration that these files may or may not be inside a subfolder with the string in its filename

Can anyone give me a hand?
Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have a folder named "DUC", but the filename doesn't have "DUC", I guess it shouldn't be listed, right?

Comment: Hello! There is no folder named "DUC" in this case, just several filenames inside several subfolders inside a specific folder, that may or may not contain the string "duc" and its variations in their names.

Comment: I meant a subfolder named for instance duce and not file with duc inside it...

Comment: @Larme Folder name - doesn't contain "duc" for sure, Subfolders - may or may not contain "duc" string in their name (as for now they don't but I can't be sure if it will happen or not in the future), and all subfolders may or may not contain files that contain the string in their names. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: I'm asking theses details, because if there was a subfolder with "duc" in its name and you wanted to still list all its files, then `find 'folder' -type f -print | sed 's_/_,_g' | grep -i 'duc' > ~/filelist.csv` would have worked.